# How to call javascript function using PF requestcontext?

Tags: primefaces

I would like to call a javascript function inside managed bean using PF requestcontext. The function doesn't seem to be executed. Wondering am I calling it correctly? I am using PF 3.5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function renderChart(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartData, categories) {}
    </script>

public void populateChart1() {
    String _LOC = "[Db1002: populateChart1]";
    System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0");

    .
    .
    .
    .
    HashMap _m_js = createJSONString2(_l);
    String _cat = (String) _m_js.get("CATEGORY");
    String _data = (String) _m_js.get("SERIES");

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    context.execute("renderChart('container','pie','Exposure by Currency', _data, _cat)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the `_data` and `_cat` variables will be passed as literals instead of their values. You just need to build the JS execution string properly:

```
String jsFunctionStr = "renderChart('container','pie','Exposure by Currency','" + _data "','" + _cat + "');";
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute(jsFunctionStr);
```